# C code (with comma operator) to Delphi

Tags: c, delphi, comma-operator

What is the equivalent Delphi code for the following in C:

```
int32 *P;
int32 c0, c1, i, t;
uint8 *X;

t = P[i], c0 = X[t], c1 = X[t + 1];
```

Frankly, the comma operator confuses me. Is the following wildly wrong?

```
{$POINTERMATH ON}
var P: ^Int32; c0, c1, i, t: Int32; X: ^UInt8;

t:= P[i];   //<--?
c0:= X[t];
c1:= X[t+1];
t:= c1;     //<--?
```

Comment: Why do you have two assignments to `t`?

Comment: I don't know Delphi, but using a comma in the C code instead of a semi-colon is not necessary in this case and unusual. It looks like someone is trying to get around a 'one statement per line' rule .

Comment: @Oli - I was working off the assumption that the last value in the chain (i.e. c1) would be assigned to t in the end

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The comma operator in C has the lowest possible precedence.  So your statement is equivalent to:

```
(t = P[i]), (c0 = X[t]), (c1 = X[t + 1]);
```

which is then evaluated from left to right.  So it's equivalent to:

```
t = P[i];
c0 = X[t];
c1 = X[t + 1];
```

However, if you had done something like this:

```
z = (a = b, c = d);
```

then it would be equivalent to this:

```
a = b;
c = d;
z = c;
```

because the comma operator "returns" its final operand.

I should also point out that because each comma is a sequence point, stuff like this is well-defined:

```
i = i + 1, i++, --i;
```

where as this isn't:

```
i = i + i++ - --i;
```

---

<sub>It almost goes without saying: if anyone wrote production C code like your first code snippet, I would have to spank them.</sub>

Comment: Your footnote is made all the better by your avatar. :-)

Comment: OK, this makes perfect sense. Also, I'll join that spanking.

Comment: +1 for the footnote! (: didn't knew that comma is an operator in C (o.O) boy... they really pushed to make it cryptic!